# I want to iterate the checked checkbox with Jquery AciTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, acitree

I want to iterate the checked checkbox with Jquery AciTree

This dont work.

```
    var api = $('#arbol_actividades').aciTree('api');
    var sel = api.checkboxes($('#arbol_actividades li'), true);
    sel.each(function(index,item){
        api.getId((item));
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What does it do? What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `item` is a DOM element, it must be jQuery-wrapped before passing it to AciTree API functions. Test:

**1**. Open [this official demo page](http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/aciTree-checkbox.html), for example, in Google Chrome.

**2.** Open the console (F12 in case of Chrome).

**3.** Check some checkboxes of the tree on the left.

**4.** Copy and paste this code into the console, and press Enter:

```
var api = $('#tree').aciTree('api'),
    leaves = $("#tree .aciTreeLi .aciTreeLeaf"),
    checked = api.checkboxes(leaves, true);

checked.each(function (index, item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    console.log(api.getId($item) + ": " + api.getLabel($item)); 
});
```

This should print the ID and the label of the selected leaf nodes. Example:

[image: Tree]

Console output:

```
3: Audi 
5: Buick
7: Chevrolet
8: Chrysler
```